# input fields not responding after added 'iscroll'-PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, iscroll

Now iam doing a phonegap application, i added 'iscroll4' to my project since i need to scroll the page, but unfortunately, after i added 'iscroll.js' my input textfields are not responding (i cant enter anything into textfeilds). my code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myScroll;
    function loaded() 
    {
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
        myScroll = new iScroll('scroller');

    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded);
```

and my scrolling part comes under the below div

```
     <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="scroller">
               //scrolling items..
           </div> 
     </div>
```

iam really struggling with this, can any one help me please..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
function loaded() {
    testScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
        useTransform: false,
        bounce: false,
        onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) 
        {
            var target = e.target;
            while (target.nodeType != 1) {
                target = target.parentNode;
            }

            if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA' && target.tagName != 'OPTION') {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
setTimeout(function () { testScroll.refresh(); }, 200);
```

Comment: @PriyanPerera: happy to know it helped.

Comment: Note that in the newest version iScroll (beta 5), onBeforeScrollStart has been renamed beforeScrollStart. Also it is an event binding. Now it would be. `testScroll.on("beforeScrollStart", function(){...});`

Comment: @Xiv: what do you have inside the function? I can't figure it out as the e parameter is not passed

Comment: @SergioMorstabilini Actually, I investigated more into this issue, and it turns out you can't preventDefault() on it anymore. Actually, iScroll5 fixes the originally described issue directly already, Preventing the event when the target is a checkbox, etc. I mistakenly thought the iScroll was preventing checkboxes when in reality it was a css rule preventing text selection.

Comment: @Xiv thanks! I thought the problem was iscroll because since removing it my code started to work. But the culprit was angularjs as explained here: http://joeriks.com/2014/02/22/faster-clicks-on-buttons-and-checkboxes-with-phonegap-angular/.
Moving the ng-click call from the <checkbox> tags to the <li> tags fixed my code. Without this change the checkboxes weren't working at all on a device with android 4 and were really slow on a device with android 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

In your function where you initiate the scroller

```
myScroll = new iScroll('scroller');
```

use `onBeforeScrollStart : null`. It means your scroller initiation should be look like this

```
myScroll = new iScroll('scroller', { onBeforeScrollStart : null });
```

It is because search for `onBeforeScrollStart` function in iScroller plugin and you can find

```
onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }
```

Simply on your mousedown it trigger this function and prevent it default event. So your input elements became non-responsive.

Therefore when you overwrite `onBeforeScrollStart` function without `e.preventDefault()` your input elements will become responsive.

Comment: thanx @Faizul Hasan: i have changed -'myScroll = new iScroll('scroller')'; with 'myScroll = new iScroll('scroller', { onBeforeScrollStart :null });' as you said, but not working!!! checked in iphone simulator..

Comment: ok.. could you please post your HTML contents too.. you have already posted two divs but could you please put the structure of scrolling items and its CSS.. because ''iScroll'' is highly depend on position and height too...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one working

```
  var selectField = document.getElementById('txt_Field');
      selectField.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e)
      {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }, false);
```