# Form Element not writeable but works with iframe

Tags: html, forms, iscroll

i created a form element like that:

```
<form id="TextForm1" name="TextForm1">
            <input type="text" id="Text1" name="Text1" value="" placeholder="" />
</form>
```

But it isn´t working in my .html site. I can´t type in something.. But if i embed it with an iframe it works perfectly.. I am using a scrolling script  "iscroll" in my content area. But i can´t figure out why it isn´t working with it.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: i´ll try.. one moment

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pS8rD/ i don´t know why, but the fiddle isn´t working properly.. :/

Comment: and i think it isn´t easy to understand.. chaos and german expressions

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the data out of the iframe into the html file? This would solve my problem. It isn´t about SEO, it´s a mobile HTML5 App.

Comment: [Please Organize your code](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/pS8rD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery so you can use [**click event**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) like: 

**[Check Out The Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/pS8rD/2/)**

```
$(yourElement).click(function()
{ 
    // your code 
});
```

I changed two functions of your code to this and removed the onclick event from the inputs:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#buttonCm').click(function(){
    var cmEingabe = document.getElementById("cm");
    var cm = cmEingabe.value;
    var cmNeu = cm - 3;
    $('#Liste').append('<br/>' + '<br/>' + '-' + ' '+ 'Bauteil passend zu ' + cmNeu +'cm' + ' ' +'Breite');
    $('#Form1').fadeOut(700);
    $('#Form2').delay(700).fadeIn(700);
});

$('#buttonCm2').click(function(){
    var cmEingabe2 = document.getElementById("cm2");
    var cm2 = cmEingabe2.value;
    $('#Liste').append('<br/>' + '<br/>' + '-' + ' '+ 'Bauteil passend zu ' + cm2 +'cm' + ' ' +'Höhe');
    $('#Form3').fadeOut(700);
    $('#Liste').delay(700).fadeIn(700);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="buttonCm" name="buttonCm" value="auswählen" />
<input type="button" id="buttonCm2" name="buttonCm2" value="auswählen" />
```

Comment: hm it makes the fiddle work, but it doesn´t fix the problem that i can´t write in the field. I don´t know why it isn´t working local but in jsfiddle.. but thank you very much for your effort

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you. But I could not find the `script` in your code to check how you had bind the `iScroll` plugin. Because `iScroll` it self prevent some events. But most probably if any form fields not responding after you bind `iScroll` means this is the solution which I used to overcome.

[input fields not responding after added 'iscroll'-PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847263/input-fields-not-responding-after-added-iscroll-phonegap/15871841#15871841)